# How to playback AVCaptureMovieFileOutput

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, playback, avcapturemoviefileoutput

I am currently able to record video to an `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput` instance , yet I can't find any sources to learn from that have show how video playback is possible like snapchat/facebook/instagram are capable of producing.

Am I supposed to use the `AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer`, and if so how would I do so as I am able to successfully record to an `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput` instance. A Solution or guidance to what is used would be very helpful!

Or Is it a specific controller, player etc? I have found the only play to be `AVPlayerViewController` however it isn't a player that is free of buttons and progress bars.

```
func captureMovie(withDelegate delegate: AVCaptureFileOutputRecordingDelegate) {
  if movieOutput.isRecording == false {
    let connection = movieOutput.connection(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)

    if (connection?.isVideoStabilizationSupported)! {
      connection?.preferredVideoStabilizationMode = AVCaptureVideoStabilizationMode.auto
    }

    let device = activeInput.device

    if (device?.isSmoothAutoFocusEnabled)! {
      do {
        try device?.lockForConfiguration()
        device?.isSmoothAutoFocusEnabled = false
        device?.unlockForConfiguration()
      }
      catch {
        print("Error smooth auto focus")
      }
    }

    let outputURL = tempURL()
    movieOutput.startRecording(toOutputFileURL: outputURL, recordingDelegate: delegate)
  } else {
    stopRecording()
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `AVCaptureMovieFileOutput` is saving the movie to a file URL. We need to use  `AVPlayerViewController` or `AVPlayerLayer` to play it.

The optimal solution for you would be play the video from `outputURL` in `AVPlayerViewController` and to hide the controls like button and progress bar use below property to set `false`

> @property(nonatomic) BOOL showsPlaybackControls;

Check below links for more info

- Apple
  [Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avkit/avplayerviewcontroller/1615824-showsplaybackcontrols?preferredLanguage=occ)
- SO Answer for [Play video with AVPlayer after
  AVCaptureMovieFileOutput](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33070851/play-video-with-avplayer-after-avcapturemoviefileoutput)